# Change user account name in Windows 8 without losing desktop settings?

Tags: networking, windows-8, user-accounts

I have inherited the computer of a former employee. My office is on a small network. I log onto the domain with his old credentials. I have tried changing it in Control Panel under user account settings but it does not give me that option. Maybe because it is the admin account? I've been using it for a while as is, but would prefer to see my name instead of old employees, but I would also like to keep all my account settings, files, docs, etc. I've also just upgraded to Windows 8. Thanks in advance for the input.

My user account properties:

[image: 1]

Old user account properties, note, there is only one tab:

[image: 2]

Computer name:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

method 1. open computer, right click -> manage, go to System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users, find your user and rename it

method 2. create a new user and copy the data from the p;d user to the new user (desktop/documents/...)

method 3. open the properties for the desktop folder and change the location (works for almost every folder in c:\Users\UserName...)

[image: sample]

Comment: Method 1 is best!